# Tkinter IntVar weird Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a new object of tk.IntVar and called it pwHardness

but its value is something random like 140358607937898IntVar.
i want the radio buttons to set the value of the variable pwHardness 1 or 2

```
import tkinter as tk

pwHardness = tk.IntVar

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1600x500")
window.configure(bg="#323e52")
Label = tk.Label(text="Password Gen", background="#323e52", foreground="#fafafa")
Label.config(width=200)
Label.config(font=("Courier", 44))


setPwRadioButtonEasy = tk.Radiobutton(
    text="Easy PW",
    padx = 20,
    var=pwHardness,
    variable=pwHardness,
    value=1,

)

setPwRadioButtonHard = tk.Radiobutton(
    text="Hard PW",
    padx = 20,
    var=pwHardness,
    variable=pwHardness,
    value=2,



)
label1 = tk.Label(text=pwHardness)


Label.pack()
setPwRadioButtonEasy.pack()

setPwRadioButtonHard.pack()
label1.pack()





window.mainloop()
```

FYI This is going to be a Password Generator.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses after `pwHardness = tk.IntVar`. It should be `pwHardness = tk.IntVar()`. Additionally, change `label1 = tk.Label(text=pwHardness)` to `label1 = tk.Label(textvar=pwHardness)`, so the label gets automatically updated. And, `tk.IntVar` must be initiated with a parent, e.g. the toplevel window. Example :

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar(root)
label = tk.Label(root, textvar=var)
label.pack()
while True:
    inp = input("enter new value ")
    if inp != "quit":
        var.set(int(inp))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: sadly it still has the same value

Comment: Unless you use `get()`, you will be referencing to the `IntVar()` instance created.

Comment: @CoolCloud i __want__ to reference to the instance, because the get method will be called internally by tkinter, and using get myself would lead to a NameError or something saying str instance has no method get

Comment: @CoolCloud it is called by tkinter internally, try my sample code which i added to my answer ! >:-@

Comment: After updating the answer with `textvar` it works. I was talking about before the update.

Comment: @CoolCloud ok, i misunderstood then !

Answer (score 0):

You aren't initializing the variable, you're just taking the `IntVar` object.

```
pwHardness = tk.IntVar()
```

would initialize a new IntVar – you're missing the parentheses.

Additionally, you're passing the `var` as a "string" value to `text`.

You'd want

```
label1 = tk.Label(text=pwHardness.get())
```

to "read" the variable into the label. However, it won't refresh automatically with that configuration.

Comment: sadly it still has the same value